# Missing parts of WMS feature with geoserver and leaflet

Tags: leaflet, geoserver, wms

I'm running into a strange problem. Using leaflet I made this attached map with a WMS layer.
When I zoom in some parts of som feature disappear.

How can I resolve this issue?
Hopefully someboby can help.

Best regards,

Michel.

[image: a]

Comment: Pretty sure they're tiling artifacts (as in https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/346467/preventing-clipped-labels-from-qgis-server-wms-in-leaflet-js/ ), but it's difficult to know more without looking at a reproducible example.

Comment: I've set gutter size and metatiles size. It has improved but I still got the same problem.